# Mysql geography point

Tags: php, mysql, sql, geolocation, geo

I am using phpmyadmin and MySql. I am trying to just insert a point, the point being a point on earth with latitude and longitude. None of the examples I have tried work. I was wondering if someone could help with an example.

These are examples I have tried.

```
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST", geography::point(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999,4326));
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST", geography::point(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999,4326));
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST", geography::point(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999,4326));
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST", geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999)',4326));
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST". (geography::point(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999,4326));
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST", (STGeomFromText('POINT(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999)',4326));
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST", STGeomFromText('POINT(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999)',4326);
INSERT INTO postTest VALUES ("TEST","TEST", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(46.7864642,-96.81803599999999)',4326);
```

this is what my table looks like.

[image]

Any advise and help would be appreciated. Also, I have not been able to get this point yet but if anyone knows how to return points between x and x distances; any examples of this would be very much appreciated as well.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Use  `SHOW CREATE TABLE postTest` output instead off a image on how the table looks like.

Comment: Which version you are using for mysql

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close because we don't know what version of MySQL which makes this question unanswerable. Though I will say this, `geography::point()` is proprietary .NET garbage from SQL Server. It's a totally ad-hoc interface into C# classes from a company too lazy to adopt the standard that **every** other database uses.